# How to control element position when changing window size for parallax purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am working on a parallax page and super frustrated when it comes down to keeping the elements position exactly as i want when the window size is changed (responsive). All my elements are text and therefor a bit challenging hence the font-sizes need to follow a long with the positioning. I do not know where to begin with this challenge, as i have been experimenting with the viewport units such as `vw` and `vh` without any luck.

I have attached three images that illustrates the element positioning i want to achieve. I have added a background color to the elements to illustrate the positions. How do i achieve this responsiveness on my elements?

Absolute position is a must hence i need to parallax the elements up and down without being independent of any orders.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/440k02wg/1/

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="header__1">
    A LOT OF TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="header__2">
    BIT MORE TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="header__3">
     SOME TEXT
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

section > div {
  position: absolute;
}

.header__1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 14vh;
}

.header__2 {
  top: 25vh;
  left: 4vw;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: orange;
  background-color: white;
}

.header__3 {
  top: 48vh;
  left: 60vw;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: blue;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[image: Normal in width]
[image: Scaled in width]
[image: Scaled in height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `position: absolute;` crucial for you? Removing that makes the issue a whole lot simpler, since block elements positioned relatively or statically always stick to their siblings. I've updated your provided example with my suggestion (and some tweaks to have the elements align accordingly).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/440k02wg/2/)

Hope it's of some help :)

Comment: I am building a parallax page where each section is 100% height and i need to move elements on top and across each other. Without absolute position i am not really able to do this..

Comment: Why wouldn't plain `z-index` work? Can you give me a fiddle with multiple sections and the parallax script in the works so I could help you out a bit more than throwing suggestions?

Comment: Lets say i want to scroll down on the page and move the top element upwards and down bottom element downwards. This is not really possible with z-index. Elements flying different directions has to be animated separately. Maybe i am a little unclear, but i am animating elements while parallaxing.